# How does JVM know about which run method to be called while executing start() method

Tags: java

In the code given below I have passed the `Temp` class object's reference id inside the `Thread` constructor call which would be catched by thread class's constructor in `Runnable` type reference variable. so I want to ask that is there any code inside that `Thread` class constructor which tells the JVM that this particular class's `run()` method is to be executed when a thread is created.

```
class Temp implements Runnable
{
   public void run()
   {
      System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
   }

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        (new Thread(new Temp())).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the Runnable interface: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html

Also, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It doesn't look like this question is about threads per se.

Comment: It doesn't happen in the constructor, it happens in the `start()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `thread.start()` method, the thread calls `runnable.run()`.

A simple way of how this could work **but really, it's not done this way due to this example not creating a new thread**, is

```
public class Thread {

   private Runnable runnable;

   public Thread(Runnable runnable) {
     this.runnable = runnable;
   }

   public void start() {
     if (runnable != null) {
       runnable.run();
     }
   }

}
```

Then when you call:

```
new Thread(this).start();
```

A new Thread will be created, assigning the *Runnable* this to the inner private member.  Later, after the object is created, `start()` will be called on the object, which will look up the private `runnable` member, and call it's `run()` method.

Comment: This is a gross simplification.

Comment: And that's why I said it didn't do it that way, genius.

Comment: Such a simplification is acceptable in context of this question, why downvoting?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That's a great suggestion, I'll add it.  Thank you.

Comment: Also, if you show that `Thread implements Runnable` and has its own `run` method, which in fact does `if (runnable != null) runnable.run();`, then you are covering quite a bit of educational ground.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik True, but in the context of this question, it's education about something else.  Please accept my apologies in not adding it, as I think it would confuse how the thread finds the right method, even if it would teach a person a thing or two about how real world `Thread`s objects work.

Comment: Just throwing in suggestions :) You are calling the shots.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik They are good suggestions, we just need a question where they can shine.  Thank you for them.

Comment: but when i genereated the html file of string class then in that i was written that the run method is called by JVM itself when the start() method executes.

Comment: If i inherit the class thread and override the run() method and access the start method with thread's object inside that class then when i execute the program the output does not show any thing..

Comment: @user2662247 The JVM "calls" all methods at the time they should be called, in the sense that it runs all the code that the compiler outputs, when it should be run.  That is a run time level idea, which parallels the source code level ideas.  As far as overriding run, and so on, you now need to dig into the actual implementation of Thread, as you are now digging into the Thread's internals.

Answer (score 0):

start() is the command to begin using the thread that you specified in method run(). Whenever start() is called, it will execute code in the run() method.

Answer (score 0):

You passed in a `Temp` object as the `Thread`'s `Runnable`. `Thread.start` will call the `run` method of its `Runnable`, so `Temp.run` is going to get called.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread`'s `start` method calls the `run` method of the object you pass as an argument to the constructor. Since you pass an object of class `Temp`, `Temp`'s run method will be called.

Answer (score 0):

What happens (in general) is this.

- The `Thread.start()` method allocates the stack, and so on.
- Then it calls the `Thread.run()` method.
- If you have overridden `Thread.run()`, then your override `run()` method is called.

  - This does ... basically what you told it to do.
- Otherwise, the `run()` method implemented by `Thread` itself is called.

  - The `Thread.run()` method checks to see if the `Thread` instance has a `Runnable` instance.
  - If it does, then `Thread.run()` calls the `run()` method on the `Runnable()`.
  - Otherwise, the `Thread.run()` method simply returns.
- Then the `Thread.run()` method returns (or terminates abnormally), the `start()` method marks the `Thread` as no longer alive, and releases the stack and dismantles other stuff associated with the Thread object.

---

> Is there any code inside that Thread class constructor which tells the JVM that this particular class's run() method is to be executed when a thread is created.

Not exactly.  The constructor stores the `Runnable` in a private variable, and the `Thread.run()` method tests the private variable ... if `Thread.run()` hasn't been overridden.